# Checking if php://memory can be written to using is_writable()

Tags: php, stream

I'm working on a stream wrapper class to implement [PSR-7](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-7-http-message.md) in a project.

In one particular use of streams I've found that `is_writable()` isn't returning the correct result for a built-in PHP stream that can be written to, e.g.: `php://memory`.

Example:

```
$handle = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
var_dump(is_writable(stream_get_meta_data($handle)['uri']));  //returns false
var_dump(fwrite($handle, 'foo'));  //int (3)
rewind($handle);
echo stream_get_contents($handle);  //prints 'foo'
```

I'm not sure if this is expected or buggy behavior.  The stream is opened in write mode, contents can be written, but `is_writable()` returns false anyhow.

I don't believe it *should* return false since `php://memory` is a read-write stream [per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). If I swap out the PHP stream for a file I get the expected results.

```
$handle = fopen('foo.txt', 'w');
var_dump(is_writable(stream_get_meta_data($handle)['uri']));  //returns true
var_dump(fwrite($handle, 'foo'));  //int (3)
rewind($handle);
echo stream_get_contents($handle);  //prints 'foo'
```

To workaround this I wrote a function that looks at the stream's `mode` metadata instead.

```
function isWritable($stream)
{
    if (!is_resource($stream) || get_resource_type($stream) !== 'stream')
    {
        //I only want this to work on stream resources.
        return false;
    }

    return (preg_match('/[w+]/', stream_get_meta_data($stream)['mode']) === 1)
        ? true
        : false;
}
```

My question(s): Why is `is_writable()` returning false for a stream that can be written to?  Is there a fundamental difference difference to PHP (in terms of streams) between a file and a built-in stream opened with `fopen()`.  Is there a better way to detect if these types of streams are writable?

Comment: Probably because `is_writable()` is checking the filesystem permissions; and php://memory is not a filesystem file

Comment: @MarkBaker I see.  So would PHP perhaps be seeing `php://memory` as nothing more than a string that simply doesn't exists as a file?  This would seem to make sense.  Would it be returning false because it can't find the file versus determining that the stream can't be written to?

Comment: Something along those lines would be my guess; it certainly can't find a physical file on disk to check permissions, so defaults to returning false